# The compactness theorem for simple groups

Tags: group-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory, simple-groups

I would like to use the compactness theorem to prove the following:

**Claim.** If $H$ is a subgroup of countable index in a simple group $G$, then there are finitely many conjugates of $H$ with trivial intersection.

Let $L = \{\cdot, e, -^{-1}, P_H, x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the language of groups with a predicate for $H$ and a sequence of constants for a set of representatives in $G$ of left cosets of $H$.

Let $p_n(x)$ be $x \in H^{x_n}\ \&\ x \neq e$.

If the Claim is not true, then $\{p_n\}$ is finitely satisfiable and by the compacntess theorem it is satisfiable. This means there is $x \neq e$, $x \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}H^{x_n}$.

However, $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}H^{x_n} = \bigcap_{g \in G}H^{g}$ that is a normal subgroup of $G$ simple, contradiction.

Is this proof a correct use of the compactness theorem?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Suppose $G$ is not saturated. Let $G'$ be a saturated elementarily extension. In $G'$ the claim is true, so we can move back to $G$

Comment: @Luis that's not correct. when you move to the saturated elementary extension you add new cosets of $H$, so the $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ will no longer represent all cosets

Comment: (in fact the structure $(G,\cdot,P_H,x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is never even $\aleph_0$-saturated, since the partial type in $v$ expressing that $v$ does not lie in any $x_nP_H$ is finitely satisfiable but not satisfiable.)

Comment: there is no reason for the intersection of the corresponding definable sets in $G'$ to be finite. indeed, if $H^{x_1}\cap\dots \cap H^{x_n}$ is infinite for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then the infinite intersection of the corresponding definable sets in $G'$ will be infinite

Comment: dear Luis, that is not correct; elementary equivalence does not mean that the structures realize the same types. for example, it is a good exercise to show that there exists an abelian group $(G,+)$ elementarily equivalent to $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ and with an element $g\in G\setminus\{0\}$ such that $g$ is divisible by $n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. (can you see how?) but there is no such element in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: you need for $(G,\cdot,P_H,x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ itself to be saturated to obtain the element you are looking for, and this can never happen

Comment: (incidentally I should say I think there is definitely not going to be a way to approach this problem using the compactness theorem. may I asked what the context of the problem is?)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I am trying to understand if the compactness theorem can give informations about subgroups of countable index in a simple group. But maybe not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The claim is false. For example, let $G$ be the automorphism group of the random graph $R$. The simplicity of this group is due to [Truss](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100063428).

For a vertex $v$ in $R$, let $G_v$ be the subgroup of $G$ consisting of those automorphisms which fix $v$.

Let $\sigma\in G$, and let $w=\sigma(v)$. The left coset $\sigma G_v$ consists of all automorphisms which map $v$ to $w$. The conjugate $G_v^\sigma = \sigma G_v \sigma^{-1}$ consists of all automorphisms which fix $w$.

It follows that $G_v$ has countable index, since there is one left coset for each $w\in R$. But no finite intersection of conjugates of $G_v$ is trivial: such an intersection consists of those automorphisms which fix finitely many elements $w_1,w_2,\dots, w_n$. But the random graph has non-trivial automorphisms fixing these elements.

To see this, pick some $x\in R$ which is distinct from the $w_i$. Now use the extension property of $R$ to find some $y\in R$ which has an edge to exactly the same $w_i$ as $x$ does, and which also has an edge to $x$. Then $x\neq y$, but there is an automorphism of $R$ fixing the $w_i$ and moving $x$ to $y$.

Comment: Thanks, I understand my mistake. The compactness theorem says that the theory is satisfiable "somewhere", not in my initial group.